# How to solve ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, js-cookie

I am setting up a modal which will hide after a user click submit the request.

```
if ( Cookies.get("submitted") && JSON.parse(Cookies.get("submitted")) ) {
         $("#booking-form-modal").hide();
         return true;
```

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ur2.png)

Comment: Probably not connected with Laravel? You have Laravel tag, but no PHP-related code...

Comment: because I omitted the code .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Cookies class is not loaded. Did you dump-autoload before you used that class so that the framework refreshes their autoload file?

Its easier to answer if you explain what framework and in what context the error appear.

Comment: Yes, I did the dump-autoload before , I am using the Laravel Framework

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple I did a mistake while giving the path of js and what I did was I gave the cookie path right below the modal script.

> Now it's working fine.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquerymodal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js')}}"></script>
```